# OveDouble counting points that fall within 2 or more overlapping buffers in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer, overlapping-features

I want to analyze crime around certain types of stores in a city. I made buffers around the stores and I need to:

1. select and extract crimes that occurred within those buffers, and
2. join the two shapefiles (buffers and crimes) so that for every crime I also have information on the store it is close to (e.g. type of store, opening date).

When two buffers overlap and a crime falls within both of them, I need to double count that crime and assign it to both buffers (and both stores).

Is there a way to do this in ArcMap?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a Spatial Join where one crime point can fall within more than one (i.e. many) store buffer polygons.

If you are not familiar with that tool then I would recommend reviewing the [Spatial Join online help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000) and then try running some tests with your data to see if the output is what you are after.